# BiCGStab using CUDA cuSparse routines from Fortran : CUSPARSE_INTERNAL_ERROR during analysis

Tags: cuda, fortran

**EDIT**

This question was labeled as off-topic
"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself..."

I have made a GitHub repo linked below with my two broken attempts at BiCGStab (with errors coming from *_analysis cuSparse functions). Since this must not be minimal enough, I have stripped everything which happens after the errors and included the code here. Since there are no fortran-to-c CUDA bindings (written in fortran) provided by NVidia, this example must include the interface module.

Desired behavior: Not having a CUSPARSE_INTERNAL_ERROR returned from cuSparse analysis routines so that I can implement BiCGStab in fortran.

Specific error: CUSPARSE_INTERNAL_ERROR, when run with cuda-memcheck, this simplified example returns the second error posted below (32 instances of read of size 4 in convert_CsrToCoo is out of bounds)

```
!
! CUDA 
!
module cuda_cusolve_map_reduced

 interface

 ! cudaMemset
 integer (c_int) function cudaMemset( devPtr,value, count ) &
                              bind (C, name="cudaMemset" ) 
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none
   type (c_ptr),value  :: devPtr
   integer(c_int), value :: value
   integer(c_size_t), value :: count
 end function cudaMemset
 ! cudaMalloc
 integer (c_int) function cudaMalloc ( buffer, size ) &
                              bind (C, name="cudaMalloc" ) 
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none
   type (c_ptr)  :: buffer
   integer (c_size_t), value :: size
 end function cudaMalloc

 integer (c_int) function cudaMemcpy ( dst, src, count, kind ) &
                              bind (C, name="cudaMemcpy" )
   ! note: cudaMemcpyHostToDevice = 1
   ! note: cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost = 2
   ! note: cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice = 3
   use iso_c_binding
   type (c_ptr), value :: dst, src
   integer (c_size_t), value :: count, kind
 end function cudaMemcpy

 ! cudaFree
 integer (c_int) function cudaFree(buffer)  bind(C, name="cudaFree")
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none
   type (c_ptr), value :: buffer
 end function cudaFree

 integer (c_int) function cudaMemGetInfo(fre, tot) &
                              bind(C, name="cudaMemGetInfo")
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none
   type(c_ptr),value :: fre
   type(c_ptr),value :: tot
 end function cudaMemGetInfo

 integer(c_int) function cusparseCreate(cusparseHandle) &
                             bind(C,name="cusparseCreate")

   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none
   type(c_ptr)::cusparseHandle
   end function cusparseCreate

 integer(c_int) function cudaStreamCreate(stream) &
                             bind(C,name="cudaStreamCreate")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr)::stream
 end function cudaStreamCreate

 integer(c_int) function cusolverSpSetStream(handle,stream) &
                             bind(C,name="cusolverSpSetStream")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr),value :: handle
 type(c_ptr),value :: stream
 end function cusolverSpSetStream

 integer(c_int) function cusparseSetStream(cusparseHandle,stream) &
                             bind(C,name="cusparseSetStream")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr),value :: cusparseHandle
 type(c_ptr),value :: stream
 end function cusparseSetStream

 integer(c_int) function cusparseCreateMatDescr(descrA) &
                             bind(C,name="cusparseCreateMatDescr")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr):: descrA
 end function cusparseCreateMatDescr


 integer(c_int) function cusparseSetMatType2(descrA,CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE) &
                             bind(C,name="cusparseSetMatType")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr), value:: descrA
 integer(c_int),value :: CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE
 end function cusparseSetMatType2

 integer(c_int) function cusparseSetMatIndexBase2(descrA,CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE) &
                             bind(C,name="cusparseSetMatIndexBase")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr), value:: descrA
 integer(c_int),value :: CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE
 end function cusparseSetMatIndexBase2

 integer(c_int) function cusparseSetMatFillMode(descrA,CUSPARSE_FILL_TYPE) &
                 bind(C,name="cusparseSetMatFillMode")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr), value:: descrA
 integer(c_int),value :: CUSPARSE_FILL_TYPE
 end function cusparseSetMatFillMode

 integer(c_int) function cusparseSetMatDiagType(descrA,CUSPARSE_DIAG_TYPE) &
                 bind(C,name="cusparseSetMatDiagType")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr), value:: descrA
 integer(c_int),value :: CUSPARSE_DIAG_TYPE
 end function cusparseSetMatDiagType


 integer(c_int) function cudaDeviceSynchronize() bind(C,name="cudaDeviceSynchronize")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 end function cudaDeviceSynchronize


 integer(c_int) function cusparseDestroy(cusparseHandle) bind(C,name="cusparseDestroy")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr),value::cusparseHandle
 end function cusparseDestroy

 integer(c_int) function cudaStreamDestroy(stream) bind(C,name="cudaStreamDestroy")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr),value :: stream
 end function cudaStreamDestroy

 integer(c_int) function cusparseDestroyMatDescr(descrA) bind(C,name="cusparseDestroyMatDescr")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr), value:: descrA
 end function cusparseDestroyMatDescr

 integer(c_int) function cusparseCreateSolveAnalysisInfo(info) &
               bind(C,name="cusparseCreateSolveAnalysisInfo")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr) :: info
 end function cusparseCreateSolveAnalysisInfo

 integer(c_int) function cusparseDcsrsv_analysis(handle,transA, &
                 m,nnz,descrA,csrValA,csrRowPtrA,csrColIndA,info) &
                 bind(C,name="cusparseDcsrsv_analysis")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr), value :: handle
 integer(c_int), value :: transA
 integer(c_int), value :: m
 integer(c_int),value :: nnz
 type(c_ptr), value :: descrA
 type(c_ptr) :: csrValA
 type(c_ptr) :: csrRowPtrA
 type(c_ptr) :: csrColIndA
 type(c_ptr), value :: info
 end function cusparseDcsrsv_analysis

 integer(c_int) function cusparseDestroySolveAnalysisInfo(info) &
                 bind(C,name="cusparseDestroySolveAnalysisInfo")

 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
 type(c_ptr),value::info
 end function cusparseDestroySolveAnalysisInfo

 end interface  

end module cuda_cusolve_map_reduced
!
!======================================================================
!======================================================================
  program main
   implicit none
   integer n,inz,i
   parameter (n=5)
   parameter (inz=13)
   double precision x(n),x_known(n),rhs(n),b(inz)
   integer ib(n+1),jb(inz)

   write(*,'(A)') 'Setting up test system'
   b(1) = 1.0d0;b(2) = 1.0d0;b(3) = 5.0d0;b(4) = 2.0d0
   b(5) = 1.0d0;b(6) = 3.0d0;b(7) = 2.0d0;b(8) = 1.0d0
   b(9) = 6.0d0;b(10) = 3.0d0;b(11) = 1.0d0;b(12) = 2.0d0
   b(13) = 1.0d0
   rhs(1) = 1.0d0;rhs(2) = 2.0d0;rhs(3) = 1.0d0
   rhs(4) = 3.0d0;rhs(5) = 0.0d0

   ib(1) = 1;ib(2) = 5;ib(3) = 7
   ib(4) = 9;ib(5) = 12;ib(6) = 14

   jb(1) = 1;jb(2) = 2;jb(3) = 4;jb(4) = 5
   jb(5) = 2;jb(6) = 3;jb(7) = 2;jb(8) = 3
   jb(9) = 1;jb(10) = 3;jb(11) = 4;jb(12) = 4
   jb(13) = 5

   x_known(1) = 0.08d0;x_known(2) = 0.2d0;x_known(3) = 0.6d0
   x_known(4) = 0.72d0;x_known(5) = -1.44d0
   x(1)=1.0d0;x(2)=1.0d0;x(3)=1.0d0
   x(4)=1.0d0;x(5)=1.0d0


  write(*,'(A)') 'Starting iterative solve'
  call cuda_BiCGStab_error(n,rhs,x,inz,ib,jb,b)
  write(*,'(A)') 'Found and Known solutions'
  do 23 i = 1,n
     write(*,*) x(i),x_known(i)
23  continue

  end program main
!
!=========================================================
subroutine cuda_BiCGStab_error(n,rhs,x,inz,ib,jb,b)
!=========================================================
use iso_c_binding
use cuda_cusolve_map_reduced
implicit none
integer n, inz
double precision x(n), rhs(n), b(inz)
target rhs,b,x
integer ib(n+1),jb(inz)
target ib,jb
integer ii,ierr,ierr2

integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)

type(c_ptr) :: cusparseHandle
type(c_ptr) :: stream
type(c_ptr) :: descrA
type(c_ptr) :: descrM
type(c_ptr) :: info_l
type(c_ptr) :: info_u
type(c_ptr) :: ArowsIndex
type(c_ptr) :: AcolsIndex
type(c_ptr) :: Aval
type(c_ptr) :: h_x  
type(c_ptr) :: h_rhs

! -------------------- pointers to device memory    
type(c_ptr) :: devPtrArowsIndex
type(c_ptr) :: devPtrAcolsIndex
type(c_ptr) :: devPtrAval
type(c_ptr) :: devPtrMrowsIndex
type(c_ptr) :: devPtrMcolsIndex
type(c_ptr) :: devPtrMval
type(c_ptr) :: devPtrX
type(c_ptr) :: devPtrF

integer*8 Arow1_i_size,Arow_d_size,Acol_d_size,Annz_i_size,Annz_d_size

integer*8 cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice
integer*4 CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_TRI
parameter (cudaMemcpyHostToDevice=1)
parameter (cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost=2)
parameter (cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice=3)
parameter (CUBLAS_OP_N=0)
parameter (CUBLAS_OP_T=1)
parameter (CUBLAS_OP_TRI=3)

ierr2 = 0

! define pointers to host memory
ArowsIndex = c_loc(ib)
AcolsIndex = c_loc(jb)
Aval = c_loc(b)
h_x  = c_loc(x)  ! x = A \ b
h_rhs  = c_loc(rhs)  ! b = ones(m,1)

Arow1_i_size=sizeof(ib(1:n+1))
Arow_d_size=sizeof(rhs(1:n))
Acol_d_size=sizeof(x(1:n))
Annz_i_size=sizeof(jb(1:inz))
Annz_d_size=sizeof(b(1:inz))

! Define the CUDA stream and matrix parameters
ierr = cusparseCreate(cusparseHandle)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseCreateMatDescr(descrA)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseCreateMatDescr(descrM)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaStreamCreate(stream) 
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseSetStream(cusparseHandle,stream) 
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseSetMatType2(descrA,CUBLAS_OP_N) 
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseSetMatIndexBase2(descrA,CUBLAS_OP_T) 
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseSetMatType2(descrM,CUBLAS_OP_N) 
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseSetMatIndexBase2(descrM,CUBLAS_OP_T) 
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
if (ierr2.ne.0) then
  write(*,'(A, I2)') 'Error during matrix setup ',ierr2
  stop
end if 
write(*,*) 'Allocating GPU memory'
ierr = cudaMalloc(devPtrX,Arow_d_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMalloc(devPtrF,Arow_d_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMalloc(devPtrAval,Annz_d_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMalloc(devPtrAcolsIndex,Annz_i_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMalloc(devPtrArowsIndex,Arow1_i_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMalloc(devPtrMval,Annz_d_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaDeviceSynchronize()
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
if (ierr2.ne.0) then
  write(*,'(A, I2)') 'Error during CUDA allocation: ',ierr2
  stop
end if 
write(*,*) 'Cleaning GPU memory'
ierr = cudaMemset(devPtrX,0,Arow_d_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemset(devPtrF,0,Arow_d_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemset(devPtrAval,0,Annz_d_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemset(devPtrAcolsIndex,0,Annz_i_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemset(devPtrArowsIndex,0,Arow1_i_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemset(devPtrMval,0,Annz_d_size)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaDeviceSynchronize()
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
if (ierr2.ne.0) then
  write(*,'(A, I3)') 'Error during CUDA memory cleaning : ',ierr2
  stop
end if 

! transfer memory over to GPU
write(*,*) 'Transferring memory to GPU'
ierr = cudaMemcpy(devPtrArowsIndex,ArowsIndex,Arow1_i_size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemcpy(devPtrAcolsIndex,AcolsIndex,Annz_i_size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemcpy(devPtrAval,Aval,Annz_d_size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemcpy(devPtrMval,devPtrAval,Annz_d_size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemcpy(devPtrX,h_x,Arow_d_size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaMemcpy(devPtrF,h_rhs,Arow_d_size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaDeviceSynchronize()
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
if (ierr2 .ne. 0 ) then
    write (*, '(A, I2)') " Error during cuda memcpy ", ierr2
    stop
end if

write(*,*) 'Creating analysis for LU'
ierr = cusparseCreateSolveAnalysisInfo(info_l)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseCreateSolveAnalysisInfo(info_u)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
if (ierr2 .ne. 0 ) then
    write (*, '(A, I2)') " Error during LU analysis creation ", ierr2
    stop
end if

write(*,*) 'Analyzing L of LU'
ierr = cusparseSetMatFillMode(descrM,CUBLAS_OP_N)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseSetMatDiagType(descrM,CUBLAS_OP_T)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaDeviceSynchronize()
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseDcsrsv_analysis(cusparseHandle,CUBLAS_OP_N,n,inz,descrM,devPtrAval,&
                               devPtrArowsIndex,devPtrAcolsIndex,info_l)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
if (ierr2 .ne. 0 ) then
    write (*, '(A, I2)') " Error during L of LU analyzing sub2 ", ierr2
    stop
end if
ierr = cudaDeviceSynchronize()
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
if (ierr2 .ne. 0 ) then
    write (*, '(A, I2)') " Error during L of LU analyzing ", ierr2
    stop
end if

ierr = cudaFree(devPtrArowsIndex)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaFree(devPtrAcolsIndex)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaFree(devPtrAval)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaFree(devPtrMrowsIndex)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaFree(devPtrMcolsIndex)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaFree(devPtrMval)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaFree(devPtrX)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaFree(devPtrF)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
if (ierr2.ne.0) then
  write(*,'(A, I2)') 'Error during cudafree: ',ierr2
  stop
end if 

ierr = cusparseDestroy(cusparseHandle)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cudaStreamDestroy(stream)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseDestroyMatDescr(descrA)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseDestroyMatDescr(descrM)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseDestroySolveAnalysisInfo(info_l)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
ierr = cusparseDestroySolveAnalysisInfo(info_u)
ierr2 = ierr2 + ierr
if (ierr2.ne.0) then
  write(*,'(A, I2)') 'Error during cuda handle destruction: ',ierr2
  stop
end if 

return
end subroutine cuda_BiCGStab_error
```

**END EDIT**

I am in the process of trying to add a CUDA implementation of the BiCGStab solver method into a legacy Fortran 77 code with the added complication of being restricted to only using a Fortran compiler (the interface to CUDA functions must be in Fortran as opposed to c/c++). The latter restriction has proven to be an extra complication, and likely the source of my problems, but my project manager is not budging on that request. I am comfortable with Fortran but effectively a novice with CUDA, so it would not surprise me in the slightest if I have missed a minor detail or have a fundamental misunderstanding.

All of my testing has been done with CUDA 9.1 Toolkit, iFort 17.0.4.196 and a Tesla P4 GPU.

After successfully implementing a direct solve method using QR decomposition (effectively a translation of the CUDA sample cuSolverSp_LinearSolver.cpp into fortran), I have run into issues while attempting to implement the iterative BiCGStab method (effectively a translation of the CUDA sample pbicgstab.cpp). My first attempt at the BiCGStab comes directly from the example (using the cusparseDcsrilu0 preconditioner) and the second, meant to sanity check the first, uses the domino-scheme cusparseDcsrilu02 preconditioner routines.

In both BiCGStab cases, the analysis phases (cusparseDcsrsv_analysis for the first attempt and cusparseDcsrilu02_analysis for the second attempt) are returning a CUSPARSE_INTERNAL_ERRROR flag which I have not been able to resolve.

I have made a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/gparsey/CUDA_FORTRAN_BiCGStab) with the necessary files to form a minimum test case of both BiCGStab methods and the QR solver method using a 5x5 matrix with 13 non-zeros and a known solution. QR works, BiCGStab methods do not.

Running cuda-memcheck with the second BiCGStab attempt (cuda_BiCGStab2)  results in:

```
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidValue (error 11) due to "invalid argument" on CUDA API call to cudaMemsetAsync.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.1 [0x332863]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.9.1 [0x37f511]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.9.1 [0x29b7fd]
=========     Host Frame:test_cuda [0x68e9]
=========     Host Frame:test_cuda [0x3334]
=========     Host Frame:test_cuda [0x1f3e]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xfd) [0x1ed1d]
=========     Host Frame:test_cuda [0x1e49]
========= 
  Error during csrilu02_analysis  7
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

while running cuda-memcheck on the first attempt of BiCGStab (cuda_BiCGStab) results in 32 (incrementing thread IDs) instances of

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x00000070 in void convert_CsrToCoo_kernel<int=1>(int const *, int, int, int*)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x0061e990 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2cd) [0x23c06d]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.9.1 [0x34dabb]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.9.1 [0x36ad0e]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.9.1 [0x2f3339]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.9.1 (cusparseXcsr2coo + 0x1fd) [0x2f355d]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.9.1 [0x2fa027]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusparse.so.9.1 [0xc4fa4]
=========     Host Frame:test_cuda [0xc9c0]
=========     Host Frame:test_cuda [0x2d6f]
=========     Host Frame:test_cuda [0x1f3e]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xfd) [0x1ed1d]
=========     Host Frame:test_cuda [0x1e49]
=========
 Error during L of LU analyzing sub2  2
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 32 errors
```

The latter line, "Error during ...", comes from my code and prints the returned integer from the CUDA function. Without cuda-memcheck both BiCGStab methods return a value of 7 which I have been interpreting as CUSPARSE_INTERNAL_ERROR however the first BiCGStab attempt returns a 2 when run with cuda-memcheck.

Any help in resolving this cusparse_internal_error, or frankly just diagnostics tips, would be greatly appreciated.

TL/DR: Stuck diagnosing a CUSPARSE_INTERNAL_ERROR from fortran implemented BiCGStab methods using cuSparse routines through a fortran interface. Internal_error comes from the *_analysis routines in the cuSparse library. I may have missed something small or I may have a fundamental misunderstanding. Any input/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `cuda-memcheck` output is useful.  Both of those outputs suggest to me API usage errors.  Specifically, I would look for a case where the API is expecting a device pointer and you are passing a host pointer.   The fortran-to-C API translation is also a common source of error, if you have possibly specified an incorrect type in one of your interfaces.  If you specified an incorrect type on a pointer argument, and effectively passed a junk pointer, it could also lead to this type of `cuda-memcheck` output.

Comment: Cheers Robert, I'll give the fortran-to-c and CUDA docs another side by side comb through; I was definitely moving through it faster by the later functions. Aside from type mismatches, do the info structure pointers (from the analysis functions) require any special treatment beyond regular pointers?

Comment: Your code is not compilable. The `target` attribute for your arguments requires an explicit interface (best using a module). It can be fixed by moving it behind `contains` of the main program.

Comment: Thank you for the response Vladimir. It does not surprise me that I might have done something incorrectly with the targets (I am used to f77), but I am able to compile the above code with both ifort (17.0.4.196) and gfortran (4.4.7-18) without errors or warnings (using <compiler> -ldl -mcmodel=medium -g min_test.f90 -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lcusolver -lcusparse -lcublas -lm) and yielding the same CUDA error. The legacy code I will eventually be using is all f77, is it possible to define the interface only in the f90 file the solver subroutine is in?

Comment: gfortran 4.8 (correctly IMHO) reports the error that @VladimirF identified and I had to fix a number of issues in that code to get it to compile and run and reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, buried in your original 2000+ LOC repro case at the end of a github link there is a mistake in the interface definition for `cusparseDcsrsv_analysis`. It should be

```
 integer(c_int) function cusparseDcsrsv_analysis(handle,transA, &
                 m,nnz,descrA,csrValA,csrRowPtrA,csrColIndA,info) &
                 bind(C,name="cusparseDcsrsv_analysis")

  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  type(c_ptr), value :: handle
  integer(c_int), value :: transA
  integer(c_int), value :: m
  integer(c_int),value :: nnz
  type(c_ptr), value :: descrA
  type(c_ptr), value :: csrValA
  type(c_ptr), value :: csrRowPtrA
  type(c_ptr), value :: csrColIndA
  type(c_ptr), value :: info
 end function cusparseDcsrsv_analysis
```

i.e. the device pointers require a `value` attribute to be correctly passed to the C subroutine.

You may well have made this mistake elsewhere  and there  might other problems elsewhere in your codebase, but after fixing the glaring errors in the MCVE you edited in your question, I could get a modified version of that repro case to run correctly.

Comment: Thank you talonmies, this seems to be solving all of my problems (fixing Dcsrsv_analysis and then propagating the missing value statements into later functions). In retrospect I can't believe I was staring at this as long as I was without seeing the missing attributes